# issue with notepad++ and iso-8859-1

Tags: windows, character-encoding, notepad++

I need to make two HTML files and I use notepad+++ to do it.
These two files must be encoded in Latin-1 A.K.A iso-8859-1.

When I select that option. notepad++ displays iso 8859-1 at the bottom-right of the screen. But notepad++ does not considere, I need to save AND

when I close the tabs and reload the files, "ANSI" is displayed at the bottom right.

What should I do ?

Comment: The encoding used to save the file is not saved in the file. Upon opening, Notepad++ does a best guess.

Comment: and how to save it ?

Comment: Notepad++ is not very good at dealing with text encoding.  It *should* have a way to select the encoding on the File + Open dialog, it doesn't.  Best way to stop this kind of lossage is to just stop using these ancient encodings, there is no point in avoiding utf8 today.

Comment: I know that. However, it's a school project and I MUST use ISO 8859-1

If I use VIM on a linux does my issue will be solved ?

Comment: You _are_ saving the file in that encoding. There's nothing else you should do. All that means is that for example an an `Ö` is saved as byte value `214`, as opposed to `153` in CP850. The application that will be _reading_ that file will have to know the file is saved in that encoding, and there's no way to do so. It just "has to know". Obligatory [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: But how to save the correct encoding ?

Comment: That is not the question you should be asking. Explain what problem you're currently having with this approach.

Comment: I must have a iso 8859-1 encoding but because of my issue, I don't know if my teacher will have the files with the iso 8859-1 encoding.

Comment: Like I said, you already **are saving the file in that encoding**. If the teacher explicitly requested that, they're teaching outdated material.

Comment: Saving to UTF-8 is only a partial solution. You'd have to save it to UTF-8 with BOM to make the editor recognise it properly on re-opening, but for instance PHP will fail to load files with a BOM propertly, or at least it will output the BOM for each file it loads, leading to unwanted side effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many character sets have characters in common. Encodings for those character sets often encode common characters with the same bytes.

If all the characters in your file are in both ISO 8859-1 and whichever ANSI character set is your default then saving as either encoding could produce a file with the same bytes. If so, this is a coincidence you should ignore.

It is great that you have been given a explicit requirement for the encoding. Two people/systems cannot definitively exchange text without both knowing the encoding. However, few systems are designed to actually save this "metadata" with text files. Most rely on a user or operating system default encoding. Many programs like Notepad++ calculate which encodings the file would be valid for and would select the default when it is one of the candidates.

This is why document specifications like HTML or XML (which are intended to be passed between systems) allow the encoding to be specified inside the text. A program reading a file can guess at encodings until it can read the file well enough to see which is specified.

To tell if it doesn't matter in your case, save two copies: one as ISO 8859-1, the other as your ANSI encoding. Then open a command prompt and run `fc /b latin.htm ansi.htm`. It might print `FC: no differences encountered`. Again, this is a coincidence. When asked for text with an ISO 8859-1 encoding, save it that way and say that's what it is when you deliver it.

To make it clear, you could specify the encoding in the text. Do it per the  standard your HTML document is: HTML 4.01 or HTML 5.

Comment: That is not necessarily true. You'll save a single byte per character, but which byte that is can depend on the encoding. So even if the ISO8859-1 version and the 'ANSI' version are the same at a certain point, there is no guarantee they will be after you add some specific characters. And also, you may not even be able to add certain characters, because they are not supported by the encoding the editor is currently set to.